# how to store dictionary items in a list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, store

This question is sorta hard to make into a one lined question so im going to have to explain. Im trying to check a given string to see if the contents in the string has whats inside the dictionary, if that situation is true for every letter in the dictionary store the keys in the list "Notes". But how do you store it in the list and how do I return it because I keep getting nothing in return heres what i have:

```
def text2notes (s):
    s = s.lower()
    noteBook = { "e":30, "t":31, "a":32, "o": 33, "i": 34, "n" :35, "h": 36}
    Notes = []
    for NoteBook in s:
        if s in noteBook:
            Notes.append(noteBook[s])
    return Notes
```

please help.

Comment: Also, unless NoteBook is a class, I would avoid the capitalization.  Same with Notes.  These should both probably be all lowercase to compy with PEP8 stadnards

Comment: If `s` is a string, you are going through it character by character. However, you are testing membership with the entire string. Should be `if NoteBook in noteBook`... Which shows you need better names too.

Comment: Is this solved now? Can we mark it as such?

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
for character in s:
    if character in noteBook:
        Notes.append(noteBook[character])
```

Also, make sure the `return Notes` is outside of the for loop.

Comment: Nice, but this will return `KeyError` if `character` is not in the dictionary. Better change it to `noteBook.get(character)`

Comment: The previous line just verified `character` *was* in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
def text2notes(s):
  s = s.lower()
  noteBook = {"e": 30, "t": 31, "a": 32, "o": 33, "i": 34, "n": 35, "h": 36}
  Notes = []
  for NoteBook in s:
    print NoteBook
    if NoteBook in noteBook:
      Notes.append(noteBook[NoteBook])

  return Notes
```

Checking for the `NoteBok` not `s` in the loop

Answer (score -1):

You could convert your check into a Boolean and  then make a conditional statement :

```
    def text2notes(s):
      s = s.lower()
      noteBook = {"e": 30, "t": 31, "a": 32, "o": 33, "i": 34, "n": 35, "h": 36}
      Notes = []
      Note = (notebook in s)
      print Note
      if Note is True:
         Notes.append(noteBook[NoteBook])

      return Notes
```

Hope this helps